# How can I return to my user's home directory after becoming root?

Tags: su

How can I switch from user to `root`? In my terminal I typed in

```
su -
```

and it took me to the `root` directory, so I need to go back to the user directory.

Comment: Remember that documentation is available on your machine; see `man su` in this case.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `cd` command or do you not know how to get the path to your user's directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the requirement is not to change directory, but to exit the root shell. (Which implicitly reverts to the caller's directory.)

You can do this with the `exit` command. A quick alternative at the start of a new line is <kbd>Ctrl d</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks so much, this work for me,  I just typed in exit and the exit work.

Comment: Thanks, the exit key work

Answer (score 3):

Just type `su` without the `-` to become root but without it being a login shell.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the question is how can I return to my user home directory after becoming root?

Comment: @YINMII you _don't_ use `-`, exactly as suggested in this answer. That way you stay in your current directory